# Get value of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this list of node :

[image]

`10,  16 ,  21,  26,  fils_de_10,  fils_de_16,  fils_de_21` are on the same level and `files_de_10` is supposed to be the child of `10` in term of the structure of my project.

I want to create a function `checkChild(node,id)` , so example when i call `checkChild(_obj,10)`, It will return `15,14,13,11,12` that are the child and sub child of `10`.

I have been trying to come up with a recursive function but it becomes messy.

It would be good if anyone already has some similar function.

Edited : This is the json data of the node :

```
var _str = '{"10":{"0":"0","1":"DISPONIBILITES","2":"t","style":"font-weight: bold;"},"16":{"0":"0","1":"TRESORERIE NETTE","2":"t","style":"font-weight: bold;"},"21":{"0":"0","1":"COMPTES","2":"t","style":"font-weight: bold;"},"26":{"0":"0","1":"LIGNE DE CREDIT BNP/HSBC","2":"f","style":"color:black;"},"fils_de_21":{"22":{"0":"21","1":"EXASOLAR SA","2":"f","style":"color:black;"},"23":{"0":"21","1":"EXASOLAR CORP","2":"f","style":"color:black;"},"24":{"0":"21","1":"EXASOLAR SARL","2":"f","style":"color:black;"},"25":{"0":"21","1":"EXASOLAR SL","2":"f","style":"color:black;"}},"fils_de_10":{"13":{"0":"10","1":"Disponibilits France","2":"t","style":"font-weight: bold;"},"14":{"0":"10","1":"Dispo exasolar SL","2":"f","style":"color:black;"},"15":{"0":"10","1":"Dispo exasolar corp","2":"f","style":"color:black;"},"fils_de_13":{"11":{"0":"13","1":"Dispo exasolar SA","2":"f","style":"color:black;"},"12":{"0":"13","1":"Dispo exasolar sarl","2":"f","style":"color:black;"}}},"fils_de_16":{"17":{"0":"16","1":"Trso nette exasolar SA","2":"f","style":"color:black;"},"18":{"0":"16","1":"Trso nette exasolar SL","2":"f","style":"color:black;"},"19":{"0":"16","1":"Trso nette exasolar corp.","2":"f","style":"color:black;"},"20":{"0":"16","1":"Trso nette exasolar sarl","2":"f","style":"color:black;"}}}';
```

Comment: Could you provide the JSON for this object so that we can easily reproduce it.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev : I edited the question and added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if what you want is something like this.

What I've done is to check inside the function is the current item key is something starting with `fils_de_`, if it is, then we call the function recursively. If not, we simply add the value to our `list` array.

Take a look and let me know if that works for you.

Cheers!

```js
var my_data = {
  10: {
    0: "0",
    1: "blabla",
    2: "t"
  },
  fils_de_10: {
    13: {
      0: "10",
      1: "blabla 10_13",
      2: "t"
    },
    14: {
      0: "10",
      1: "blabla 10_14",
      2: "t"
    },
    15: {
      0: "10",
      1: "blabla 10_15",
      2: "t"
    },
    fils_de_13: {
      11: {
        0: "10",
        1: "blabla 10_11",
        2: "t"
      },
      12: {
        0: "10",
        1: "blabla 10_12",
        2: "t"
      }
    }
  }
};

function checkChild(node,id) {
  var list = [];
  
  if(node['fils_de_'+id])
    for (var item in node['fils_de_'+id])
      if(item.match(/fils\_de\_(\d+)/))
        list.push(...checkChild(node['fils_de_'+id], item.split('_')[2]));
      else
        list.push(item);
  else
    for (var item in node)
     if(item.match(/fils\_de\_(\d+)/))
       list.push(...checkChild(node[item], id));
  
  return list;
}

console.log(checkChild(my_data, 10));
console.log(checkChild(my_data, 13));
```

Comment: We are almost there, there is one thing that I want  is, when we do `console.log(checkChild(my_data, 13)`   , `11, 12` should be shown as well.

Comment: I see... that's something else. how deep you need to look for it in your object? fils_de_13 it's always in the second level?

Comment: For now, we have only two level. And yeah, fils_de_13 is always in the second level. it won't be duplicated.

Comment: I've edited my answer adding a condition for the functionality you are looking for. I hope it helps you!! cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right, what you need is a simple [Breadth-first tree traversing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Check out the well known algorithm - it should work.

In steps you should:

1. Build the name of the node you want to examine ("fils_de_10" in you example).
2. Traverse the tree until you find this node.
3. Traverse a subtree of this node and store all leaves as your result.

Hope it works.